# Get position or range of alias

Tags: vhdl

Suppose I have an alias for a a single bit or number of bits in a std_logic_vector declared such as this:

```
signal CR : std_logic_vector(7 downto 0);
alias CR_ARM : std_logic is CR(0);
alias CR_PS  : std_logic_vector(3 downto 0) is CR(7 downto 4);
```

How can I access the range or position of the alias such as:

```
singal tmp : std_logic_vector(7 downto 0); -- output bus vector
tmp(CR_ARM'range) <= CR_ARM; -- does not compile
```

Comment: `CR_ARM` is a scalar (`std_logic`) => no range.

Comment: I bet he wants the attribute to return to which index of CR `CR_ARM` is coupled. I don't think this is possible. I would try a different approach, for instance via a set of constants indicating bit mappings.

Comment: *`CR_ARM` is a scalar (`std_logic`) => no range*. std_logic is a scalar type, a character enumerated type. The distinction is between a constrained range of ordered values and index constraint specifying elements of an array object.  An object of a scalar type has a possible range of values but not an element index range. `'range` is an array attribute and not an attribute of a type or an object. IEEE Std 1076-2008 5. Types, 5.1 General, 16.2.3 Predefined attributes of arrays.

Comment: If you have an 8-bit value where various parts of it have particular meanings, I would define a record type containing these parts separately, and then implement a conversion function from `std_logic_vector`.

Answer (score 1):

Range is only defined for array types. Even when VHDL-2017 will add ranges for scalar types, it won't solve your problem, because you want to know for which bit the alias was created.

Aliases are transparent in VHDL. There is no mechanism to reflect about aliases.

You could use this workaround, which doesn't look very nice:

```
signal CR : std_logic_vector(7 downto 0);
alias CR_ARM : std_logic_vector is CR(0 downto 0);

signal tmp : std_logic_vector(7 downto 0); -- output bus vector

-- now a slice name works
tmp(CR_ARM'range) <= CR_ARM;
```

Your second example won't work as expected. You should declare the alias with the same range constraints otherwise you will assign other bits when you use `CR_PS'range`.